# Mouse only scrolls down now to a certain point, then stops

Tags: mouse, scrolling, logitech-mouse

I have a very strange issue where if I am on the top of a long web page, or in a code editor or anywhere else that needs to scroll down, the mouse wheel will scroll down but then STOP scrolling once it gets to a certain threshold.   From there, I can scroll up with the wheel and down again until it hits this magic threshold and stops.

For example, on Reddit, it will scroll about 2 pages and then refuse to scroll further.  In my code editor, both Visual Studio and VS Code, it does the same thing.  I can scroll up and down all I please at the TOP of the code/page, but scrolling down hits a hard "wall" and refuses to scroll further.

This just started happening today.  I've rebooted to no avail.

It's very strange.  The mouse isn't broken, it will happily scroll up and down all day, as long as I am above this magic cutoff point.  Once I scroll down and it hits this point, it won't scroll further.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here?   Windows 11 21H2 build 22000.376.

I can still use the middle mouse button to "auto-scroll" down further, and using the keyboard works fine to continue down.  But the mouse wheel refuses to go any further.

Comment: Update Mouse Driver?   No issue with Windows 11 Pro up to date and a Logitech Mouse (and Keyboard).

Comment: Faulty mouse, maybe? It may be worth testing with another mouse. I have had a number of Logitech mice develop scroll wheel issues over the past decade or so.

Comment: @Anaksunaman The strange thing is it scrolls up and down fine, as long as I am near the TOP of a webpage or in my code editor.  It will scroll down to a certain point and then hit a wall and completely stop scrolling.  If I go back to the top of the page, it scrolls down fine.  I don't understand what this "wall" is but I will try with another mouse, thanks.

Comment: @John That's exactly what I am using, Logitech mouse and keyboard via a unified receiver.  I ordered a new mouse (M705) .... we'll see where that gets me.

Answer (score 0):

This problem resolved itself after I woke up and unlocked the computer.

I kid you not, and I realize that isn't even a good "answer", but the mouse was not working, even after reboots.  Now, everything is normal again after the computer went to "sleep" and I re-entered Windows 11.

I put "sleep" in quotes because I run this laptop (when on power) without sleeping.  It just turns off the monitor.

I truly don't understand how the problem persisted between reboots but now is working fine again.  I'd say faulty mouse, but it's not, as it was able to scroll up/down without hesitation at the *top* of web pages and editors.  It was only when it hit this "wall" I could no longer scroll down.

And that affected all programs, from the web browser to VS Code to Microsoft Word and Excel.

The point where it would "stop" seemed to vary, but it was generally around 2x the screen height it would decide it didn't want to scroll down anymore.

Now it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Windows 10 user, I experienced a similar issue all of a sudden and stumbled on this page. I also have a Logitech mouse and keyboard with unified receiver. Like the OP, I found that the mouse wheel scrolls down from the top to a certain point and then hits a wall. If I rolled the wheel more "forcefully" though, I was able to continue past the wall.

I doubt it was a physical issue with the mouse wheel because the scrolling can work normally but only near the top region of the page.

Restarting or putting the computer to sleep didn't work for me. I went into the advanced mouse settings and changed them back and forth, e.g. increased/decreased the number of lines to scroll at a time, and that eventually worked!